# processing a txt file in parallel

Tags: python, text, gnu, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have a huge txt file with 200,000 lines of sentences
(line format example: file_name.wav| some transcript blabla).

I would like to pipe each line to a python script, in parallel. I have a python script that takes sentences as input, phonemizes them, and saves them to a file.

I tried something like this using gnu parallel:

```
cat test.txt | parallel python singlePhonemize.py
```

which throws EOF when reading a line. I need to be able to use parallel for this and it must be able to get past the 'argument list too long error'

Here is my python script:

```
import subprocess
metadataLine=input()    
metadataLine=metadataLine.split('|')                                             

file_name=metadataLine[0][:-4]                                                        
raw_transcript=metadataLine[1]                                                          

command='echo \"{}\" | phonemize -l en-us'.format(raw_transcript)                   
festival_phonemized_transcript=subprocess.check_output(command , shell=True).decode();

new_file_name=file_name+'.txt'                                                                                                                                 
new_file_path='/folder/'+new_file_name 

with open(new_file_path,'w') as file:                                                                
        file.write(festival_phonemized_transcript)
```

Comment: Show us 3 lines of input and the corresponding 3 commands you want run based on those 3 lines of input.